# ASP.NET MVC Custom Error Page, one page for multiple errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add custom error page to my web application and I did the following based on some answers on stack overflow,
**The Controller**

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    public ViewResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 404;  //you may want to set this to 200
        return View("NotFound");
    }

}
```

I have added two views, Error.cshtml and NotFound.cshtml

and I added the following to the web.config file:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
  <error redirect="~/Error/Error" statusCode="404" />
  
  
</customErrors>
```

I need to have one page for all errors, or for the same error category, for example one page for all 400s errors so instead of doing

```
 <error redirect="~/Error/Error" statusCode="400" />
 <error redirect="~/Error/Error" statusCode="401" />
 <error redirect="~/Error/Error" statusCode="402" />
```

do something like

```
 <error redirect="~/Error/Error" statusCode="40***" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make your Error Controller like below for a simple solution

```
 public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    // GET: Error
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

And use the code below in your web.config file

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="Error" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use range attributes here.  For example given this set of ranges

What is range?

- Range    It matches an integer within a range of values. {ParameterName:range(1,500)}

Some known example ranges:

- Informational responses (100–199)
- Successful responses (200–299)
- Redirection messages (300–399)
- Client error responses (400–499)
- Server error responses (500–599)

Now, given that I can create a controller with a route attribute and define a range - using the method name to help document what it is about for maintenance purposes: Here are a couple of those, will leave it to you to determine the view etc. here.

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("error/{statusCode:int:range(100,199)}")]
    public ActionResult InformationalResponse(int statusCode)
    {               
        return View();
    }
    [Route("error/{statusCode:int:range(400,499)}")]
    public ActionResult ClientErrorResponse(int statusCode)
    {               
        return View();
    }

}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

New to routing? https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/10/28/asp-net-mvc-5-1-new.aspx

Attribute routing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attribute-routing-for-rest-apis